# How do I convert from a &mut T to a &mut U type?

Tags: rust, type-conversion

I'm trying to understand the borrow checker. I have a function with the signature

```
fn SerializeChar(&mut self, value: &mut u8)
```

I would like to get data from `u8` and `i8` because I don't care about the sign:

```
let mut test: i8 = 0; 
thing.SerializeChar(&mut test); //Error: &mut u8 expected
```

That's fine, but how exactly do I cast this?

`&mut (test as u8)` is not the same thing. Is there any safe or unsafe way to pass test as an argument to `SerializeChar` similar to just casting in C++? Also I would not want to destroy `test` when I do it, as I still need `test`, and still want it as an `i8`, not a `u8`.

I'm not trying to clone the value. I want the address to `test`, because data in `SerializeChar` is mutable and needs to modify whatever is put in. In C++ terms I don't want a `char`, I want a `*char` because I need to modify 8 bits in memory. It's possible that I can do two separate versions of `SerializeChar`, but before that I wanted to know if it's possible to actually do something like `*u8(test)` that the borrow checker is okay with.

Comment: The way you mention is the only way to cast i guess... it's a safe cast and cannot run to a runtime exception afaik.

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `serialize_char` instead, please.

Comment: If you "don't care about the sign", why are you using `i8` instead of `u8` to begin with?

Comment: Because something cares about the sign, but I only care about it's representation in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, this has nothing to do with the borrow checker. Being told that one type is not the same as another type is the purview of the **type** checker.

> Is there any safe or unsafe way to pass `test` as an argument to `SerializeChar` similar to just casting in C++?

#### Via raw pointers

Convert it in this sequence:

1. `&mut i8`
2. `*mut i8`
3. `*mut u8`
4. `&mut u8`

```
fn serialize_char(value: &mut u8) {
    *value = std::u8::MAX
}

fn main() {
    let mut test: i8 = 0;
    serialize_char(unsafe { &mut *(&mut test as *mut i8 as *mut u8) });
    println!("{}", test); // -1
}
```

See also:

- [Casts in the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/casts.html)

#### `transmute`

Using `as` should always be your first attempt, but there's also the Big Hammer of [`transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html). This allows you do all sorts of bad things compared to the simpler sequence of `as` casts and is not favored when there's an alternative:

```
use std::mem;

fn serialize_char(value: &mut u8) {
    *value = std::u8::MAX
}

fn main() {
    let mut test: i8 = 0;
    serialize_char(unsafe { mem::transmute(&mut test) });
    println!("{}", test); // -1
}
```

See also:

- [Transmutes in the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/transmutes.html)

#### Safety

All of the casts via `as` are safe, although they might produce bogus or unexpected data.

Converting from `*mut u8` to `&mut u8` or using `transmute` is unsafe because the programmer must ensure that:

- the rules of references are upheld
- the values all have valid values for their types

We know that the reference is valid: there's still only one mutable reference and it points to live data.

A `u8` and an `i8` are both valid for any 8-bit pattern of bits, even though the semantic values may change, as shown by how `u8::MAX` becomes `-1` .

---

All this being said, that doesn't mean that there aren't better ways to accomplish your goal. As [Laney mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55180019/155423), you could create a trait for interesting types and hide the unsafe code internal to the implementations. This allows your users to avoid the unsafety.

You could also use a macro to create multiple similar functions without actually having them be the same.

There’s probably a higher level way of solving your real problem as well. Why must you mutate the data in place here? It seems very unusual for serialization.

Comment: What guarantees are there that a positive `i8` value will have the same representation as a `u8`?

Comment: @PeterHall rust state use two complement representation, https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/numeric.html

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this safely. Once you have a `&mut` reference to a `u8`, the code using it can only treat it as a `u8`, and you'd need some unsafe code to do the conversions.

`as` works with primitive numeric values because it copies the data in memory, and it can take care of any conversions at that point. This won't work with a reference because it can't change the original value.

If you absolutely can't change the signature of `thing.serialize_char`, *and* you can't change the type of the `test` variable, a workaround is to use another variable and then update the original afterwards:

```
let mut test: i8 = 0; 

let mut test_u8 = test as u8;
thing.serialize_char(&mut test_u8);
test = test_u8 as i8;
```

This will not work if `serialize_char` needs the reference for longer than the function call - but if that is the case the borrow-checker will soon let you know!

Answer (score 1):

Traits in Rust can be generic, so you can define a trait with signature like this:

```rust
trait SerializeChar<T> {
    fn serialize_char(&mut self, value: &mut T);
}
```

and then implement it for your structure with `T = u8` and `T = i8`:

```rust
struct Thing {}

impl SerializeChar<u8> for Thing {
    fn serialize_char(&mut self, value: &mut u8) { *value = 55; }
}

impl SerializeChar<i8> for Thing {
    fn serialize_char(&mut self, value: &mut i8) { *value = 56; }
}
```

test:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = 0u8;
    let mut b = 0i8;
    let mut thing = Thing{};
    thing.serialize_char(&mut a);
    thing.serialize_char(&mut b);
    dbg!(a);
    dbg!(b);
}
```